# How do You Convert an AnyKeyPath to a WritableKeyPath?

Tags: swift, casting, swift4, keypaths

I have an array of enum cases, where each case has a `keyPath` property, which returns an `AnyKeyPath` matching the classes property with the same name as the enum case:

```
protocol PathAccessor: CodingKey {
    var keyPath: AnyKeyPath { get }
    static var allCases: [Self] { get }

    init?(rawValue: Int)
}

extension PathAccessor {
    static var allCases: [Self] {
        var cases: [Self] = []
        var index: Int = 0
        while let element = Self.init(rawValue: index) {
            cases.append(element)
            index += 1
        }

        return cases
    }
}

class Robot {

    let name: String
    var age: Int
    var powered: Bool
    var hasItch: Bool?

    enum CodingKeys: Int, PathAccessor {
        case name
        case age
        case powered
        case hasItch

        var keyPath: AnyKeyPath {
            switch self {
            case .name: return \Robot.name
            case .age: return \Robot.age
            case .powered: return \Robot.powered
            case .hasItch: return \Robot.hasItch
            }
        }
    }

    init(name: String, age: Int, powered: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.powered = powered
    }
}

for element in Robot.CodingKeys.allCases {
    // Trying to implement
}
```

In the loop above, I want to check the `keyPath` property of the case to see if it is a `WritableKeyPath`, and if it is, create a closure that will modify the property that the key path accesses.

The problem with this is that a `WritableKeyPath` is a generic type. I know the `Root` type, but the `Value` type could be almost any type in existence. I could create a bunch of cases for each of most likely types:

```
if let path = element.keyPath as? WritableKeyPath<Robot, Int> {

} else if let path = element.keyPath as? WritableKeyPath<Robot, String> {

} // So on and so forth
```

But that is time consuming, ugly, and hard to maintain.

I did try to cast to a dynamic type, but that gives a compiler error (`Use of undeclared type 'valueType'`):

```
let valueType = type(of: element.keyPath).valueType
guard let path = element.keyPath as? WritableKeyPath<Self, valueType> else {
    continue
}
```

I could use a protocol that the types already conform to, but for some reason, that is also failing:

```
guard let path = element.keyPath as? WritableKeyPath<Robot, NodeInitializable> else {
    print("bad")
    continue
}
print("good")

// Output:
// bad
// bad
// bad
// bad
```

So, is it even *possible* to convert an `AnyKeyPath` to a `WritableKeyPath` without a huge string of unwrapping statements or weird hacks that shouldn't be used in production?

Comment: I am looking for the same answer as you, did you ever found the answer? Also, why didnt you use PartialKeyPath?

Comment: @RicardoDuarte There isn't a way to accomplish this currently. I didn't user PartialKeyPath because that just uses Any as its value type.

Answer (score 2):

After a few hours playing around with code, the best I got was this:

```
struct Person {
var name: String
var collection: [String]
var optionalCollection: [String]?
let birthdate: Date

fileprivate func keyPath<V>(from label: String, type: V.Type) -> WritableKeyPath<Person, V> {
    print("type: \(type)")
    let valuePair: [String: PartialKeyPath<Person>] = ["name": \Person.name,
                                                       "birthdate": \Person.birthdate,
                                                       "collection": \Person.collection,
                                                       "optionalCollection": \Person.optionalCollection]
    return valuePair[label] as! WritableKeyPath<Person, V>
}


}



var person = Person(name: "john",
                    collection: [],
                    optionalCollection: ["gotcha"],
                    birthdate: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0))


let name = person[keyPath: person.keyPath(from: "name", type: String.self)] // john
let birthdate = person[keyPath: person.keyPath(from: "birthdate", type: Date.self)] // Jan 1, 1970
let collection = person[keyPath: person.keyPath(from: "collection", type: Array<String>.self)] // []
let optionalCollection = person[keyPath: person.keyPath(from: "optionalCollection", type: Optional<Array<String>>.self)] // ["gotcha"]
```

However you must always pass the type as parameter. If only the Mirror class allowed us to get the actual type from each property.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still interested, one could use the following code:

Conform all the value types you will be using to a protocol and add this function

```
protocol NodeInitializable {
   internal static func write<K>(keyPath: AnyKeyPath, object: inout K, value: Any?) {
       let path = keyPath as? ReferenceWritableKeyPath<K, Self> // use ReferenceWritableKeyPath for classes and WritableKeyPath for structs
       object[keyPath: path!] = value as! Self // or any other conversion to convert the value you have to the type you want

   }
}
```

Then, for example, to change the name property of the Robot class (class mentioned in question), one could do this:

```
// conform String to the new protocol
extension String: NodeInitializable {

}

// and then
let robot = Robot()

let nameAnyKeyPath: AnyKeyPath = \Robot.name
var someNewValue: Any = "New Robot Name"

let valueType = type(of: someNewValue) as! NodeInitializable.Type
valueType.write(keyPath: nameAnykeyPath, object: &robot, value: someNewValue)

print(robot.name) // should print 'New Robot Name'
```

Comment: I'm having trouble using this to write to CNContact.givenName. Any ideas?