# Writable keypath with undefined Class

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, keypaths

I need an array of writable keypaths to edit variables, but the Class is undefined. How could I do something like this ?

```
var properties: [ WritableKeyPath< AnyClass, Double > ]

properties.append( \Class1.tag )
properties.append( \AnyClass2.volume )

func setPropertie (keyIndex: Int, value : Double) {
    anyObject[keyPath: properties[keyIndex] ] = value
}
```

In this case, trying to append( \Class1.tag ) got this error: Type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type') has no member 'threshold'

Answer (score 1):

Your `WritableKeyPath<AnyClass,Double>` is made to be take `AnyClass` but you're putting class specific keypaths.

`Class1` as `AnyClass` would lose access to it's `tag` object.
Similarly `AnyClass2` as `AnyClass` would also lose access to it's `volume` object.
Hence `\Class1.tag` and `\AnyClass2.volume` won't work for a `WritableKeyPath<AnyClass,Double>`

What you could do instead is:

```
var properties = [AnyKeyPath]()
properties.append(\Class1.tag)
properties.append(\AnyClass2.volume)
```

Comment: anyVar[keyPath: properties[index] ] = 50 ... And now I get this : " Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Any?' "

Comment: @Fischer Hm... that's now a problem. Read: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80268. You can store `AnyKeyPath`s for reading but when it comes to writing... I am not sure how to do that. I will try nonetheless and get back if I find something.

Comment: @Fischer Seems there's already a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427508/how-do-you-convert-an-anykeypath-to-a-writablekeypath) regarding your next hurdle but it's unanswered so far.

Comment: @Fischer so any progress here? how would you later on know which `keyIndex` will give you the `keyPath` associated to it's respective class? Because I can see this getting pretty messy if you plan to have an array of generic `WritableKeyPath`s; assuming if that were even possible, which it isn't right now. Are you sure you're going down the right `path` (pun)?

Comment: Nothing. I decided to change my code switching between indexes provided by tags. Would be better with keyIndex. Now I have more lines of code, but works for me

Comment: Any way, this post could help: Take a look to this example ... kp.rootType  ...  kp.valueType ... https://www.klundberg.com/blog/swift-4-keypaths-and-you/

Comment: @Fischer I have seen this link before and also while trying to find you a solution but I never found it to work. I get `Static member 'rootType' cannot be used on instance of type 'AnyKeyPath'`